# MS SQL Trigger needed for Update a row, then delete from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

i am looking for a trigger for ms sql. I have one table `dbo.item`, and another table `dbo.ean`. In frontend i edit this table, and once it is finished, i want to get a number from `dbo.ean` added to `dbo.item`. Once it got edited, it should be deleted from dbo.ean, so it is not used a second time.Furthermore a condition is, if the sku is like `'%%%%W'....`

**Table design:**

dbo.item
sku              name                            ean
5510W       testproduct 1 
5511W       testproduct 2 
5512W       testproduct 3 
5513W       testproduct 4 
5514W       testproduct 5 

dbo.ean

ean
111111
222222
333333
444444
555555

I've used the search function, but my knowledge of **sql** is rather small :D, so any help or hints are highly appreciated,

Comment: My Suggestion would be to write a Stored Proc with all this functionality and call it from front end/service instead of going for a trigger

Comment: It is for a kinf of ERP system with connection to ebay, so call it from front end will be not possible.

Comment: How is data getting saved in DB? There should be some option that you should have provided to do it. My suggestion to add this piece of SQL there.

Comment: How it is saved, thats a good question. Maybe this helps. As said it`s a kind of erp ssystem with ebay connection. EAN codes are necessary, to start the offer on ebay. While preparing the offer, we have the option to add an ean code manually, and delete it from an excel sheet, so it wont get used a second time. So, my thought now is, i create a dbo.ean table, import the ean codes to this table. Once i save the offer, the db writes the ean into the field via the trigger, and deletes it from the created dbo.ean table.

Comment: I have other triggers is use, i.e setting automatical the shipping options , and such things, these work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

On SqlServer There are two tables for triggers (inserted/deleted) that are a view of changes applied on original table.

You Can use a trigger like this:
Create Trigger tr_ondelete on item After delete as

Delete from ean where ean Is in (select ean from deleted)

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a try